# php - How to only show 1 flash message - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, flash-message

Hello im newbie in laravel so i really need some help. I want to create a code where only 1 flash message will show. In my case when I update user or store will appear 2 flash message "User updated successfully" and "Store updated successfully". I just want to show only one flash message.

This is my code

```
<div class="content">
  @include('flash::message')
   @include('adminlte-templates::common.errors')
   <div class="box box-primary">
       <div class="box-body">
           <div class="row">
                {!! Form::model($users, ['route' => ['users.update', $store->user_id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}

                    @include('users.fields',['user'=>$users])

               {!! Form::close() !!}
             </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

```
<div class="content">
@include('flash::message')
   @include('adminlte-templates::common.errors')
   <div class="box box-primary">
       <div class="box-body">
           <div class="row">
               {!! Form::model($store, ['route' => ['stores.update', $store->id], 'method' => 'patch' , 'files' => true]) !!}

                    @include('stores.fields')


               {!! Form::close() !!}                   
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

[image: This is the view of 2 flash message from User]

[image: This is the view of 2 flash message from Store]

Comment: Add only single flash message, so that single message is visible else it'll duplicate for each inclusion of flash message.

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva Can u make the code for me im really newbie in Laravel :D

Comment: Remove `@include('flash::message')` from both contents and add only single `@include('flash::message')` on top of page.

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva thanks for help but where i should put the code @include('flash::message') in my code https://imgur.com/a/1qm18

Comment: @SahatRiyanto Is my answer works or not?

Comment: @HirenGohel Sorry for late response :D it still didint work. Any other help? :D

Comment: @SahatRiyanto Have you tried my answer? After many days, you replied!

Comment: @HirenGohel Yes i've tried your answer but it still didnt work. Sorry for late response i have so many tasks to do :D

Comment: Any errors you got? Because it's laravel flash mesaages provide!

Comment: @HirenGohel No errors just still show 2 flash message and i dont know why

Comment: @HirenGohel Maybe u can make any other code if u had im really newbie in Laravel sorry :D

Comment: Remove your code and make it as i am defined in my answer. In your controller and in your view, do as i mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all flash messages from divs and add only single flash message above.

```
//add only this above all div and remove others
@include('flash::message')

<div class="content">
    @include('adminlte-templates::common.errors')
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-body">
           <div class="row">
               {!! Form::model($users, ['route' => ['users.update', $store->user_id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}

                @include('users.fields',['user'=>$users])

               {!! Form::close() !!}
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
   @include('adminlte-templates::common.errors')
   <div class="box box-primary">
       <div class="box-body">
           <div class="row">
               {!! Form::model($store, ['route' => ['stores.update', $store->id], 'method' => 'patch' , 'files' => true]) !!}

                @include('stores.fields')


               {!! Form::close() !!}                   
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes its worked but I have to put a flash message "User updated successfully" under the User and "Store updated successfully"  under the store not like this https://imgur.com/a/uruNF

Comment: You can pass it from your controller: `$request->session()->flash('user', 'User updated successfully');
            return redirect('your_page_name');` same as for `store`

Comment: this is my full code if u want to see https://imgur.com/a/FVD3T and https://imgur.com/a/VrTsr

Comment: @SahatRiyanto are you using flash package to show flash session data ?

Comment: Sorry for late reponse, whats flash package mean? this is my controller https://imgur.com/a/QaLHV

Comment: @HirenGohel maybe u can make the code i've uploaded my controller im really newbie in laravel :D